# How to structure the code of an application

Tags: qt

I have a general question about how to structure the code of an application.
I am using QT for the GUI and by clicking different GUI elements, there is a corresponding slot (event handler). All this happens in the Main Window class. But now I was wondering how can it be better structured. For example if a slot creates an object and another slot (function) wants access to this object, what is the best solution? Having a variable in the main window that stores the object is not ideal I think. Maybe a general (static?) class that holds all the information and can be accessed by everybody?

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a static class that can be accessed by everybody. Global state, generally speaking, is bad.

If you need to have specific qobjects aware of signals happening from an object, then you need to connect them up, obviously. If the object is going to live forever, then you can probably just parent the object you're creating with the main window, but this necessitates that you can connect all of your signals up to this new object at the time of its creation.

At some point, you're going to need to store a collection of objects that need to dynamically connect and unconnect signals at various moments. In general, you need to sit and think about the purpose of the object and decide who should have access to it. Then, you create interfaces to manage the creation, referencing, and destruction of this object. Then, you create concrete implementations of these interfaces and you only pass to other classes the functionality it needs. If an object needs to know how to create but not use, you pass a creator to the class. If it needs to know how to use but not create, you pass a "user." This situation can get unimaginably complex, so you've got to make good design decisions early that segregate distinct purposes from each other.

With your extremely general question, this is the best I can offer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was just thinking in general terms, not in qt term. In general, if I build an application, how can I organize my code? For example, my application opens an image, extract stuff from it, stores it in vectors, ... then process these vectors, stores it, .... How can you organize all this? You need to write a lot of classes, one for file reading and extraction, the other for processing, the other for I don't know storing, and so on. But all these classe should communicate somehow.

Comment: @Tom I think you need to study the fundamentals of OOP design. It's too much to cover on SO. Note, OOP design is different than understanding the technical workings of an OOP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You ask: "If a slot creates an object and another slot (function) wants access to this object, what is the best solution?"

Assuming that this is a fitting design for your particular application (a **big if**!), it's easy to do. Just pass the pointer to the newly made instance as a parameter in the signal. Couldn't be any simpler than that. Make sure that you decide (and stick to it!) on what's the lifetime and ownership of the created instance. The code below simply makes the new instance a child of the object in which it was created. That may or may not apply in your particular case.

```
class Class : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Class(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) { ... }
signals:
  void madeNew(Class *);
public slots:
  void creator() {
    emit madeNew(new Class(this));
  }
  void consumer(Class * instance) {
    // do something with the new instance
  }
};
```

Comment: About OOP design: normally books about OOP teach you stuff like inheritance, polymorfism and so on. But this is not exactly what I am searching for. I did not find until now a book about how to write complex applications. Usually almost every application opens a file, works on it, and stores it. For this reason I was thinknig how to best organize the code (global coordination or distributed). I mean, sure there are design patterns and so on, but this is not exactly the structure.

Comment: OOP is a toolset. You need to learn your trade (software engineering) in order to know which tools to use and when. There's no substitute for doing it again and again, slightly less worse each time. If you can do an apprenticeship under direction of a skilled developer/engineer, that'll speed things up, but a human has to be involved. Either you yourself by coding a lot and learning from your own mistakes, or someone with plenty of skill. Pair programming works well. Find a skilled partner and learn.